# GWT CellList onBrowserEvent2() is not called after row data is updated

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT 2.1.0

**What I have:**

- I have a `CustomCellList` which `extends CellList`, I am overriding `onBrowserEvent2(event)` in this `CustomCellList`. Data is provided by a `AsyncDataProvider`.
- SetSelectionModel : `NoSelectionModel`

**Problem:**

The `onBrowserEvent2(event)` is called only once when data is added to `CustomCellList`. After I call `AsyncDataProvider#updateRowData()`, the onBrowserEvent2() is not called at upon clicking any of the `CustomCellList` cells.

**What I tried:**

I tried finding a solution on google, but all the solutions tell about passing an optional CellPreviewHandler parameter addSelectionChangeHandler() method, but this is available in **GWT 2.1.1+** versions, while I am using **V2.1.0**. I can;t upgrade to V2.1.1 as it has lot of API changes and the business requirement does not allow me to upgrade GWT version.

Can you help me out with this please?

Thanks!

Comment: It is onBrowserEvent2 called only when browser events occurs?

Comment: Yes.. onBrowserEvent2 is called when browser event occurs.

Comment: Adding data don't trigger a Browser Event.

Comment: Its not about adding data, its about click events after updating data. So the CellList is having some initial data, and I click on some data, it triggers click event. After updating the CellList data and then if I click on something, it does not trigger click event.

Comment: Never mind, I found the root cause for this behaviour. The links in the cellList were pointing to another instance and the another instance did not have my code changes!

Comment: OK. please reply to your issue and accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the question anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, the links in the CellList were pointing to another server instance, so when I clicked on the data in CellList, it would load page from another server instance which didn;t have the latest code changes! It worked otherwise.